# How do you make the flap t sound as in "Better" and "letter"?

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent

How do I make the flap/tap t sound as in words like: better, matter, stutter, moto, but I'm, bottom and so?

Comment: Most Americans will pronounce those as *bedder* and *ledder*, with a de-emphasis and reduction of the phoneme altogether.

Comment: i know but can you explain to me EXACTLY how to produce that sound because whenever I try to do it it just sounds like a strong D as in Doctor

Comment: Well, when I say that phoneme, my tongue never *quite* reaches the alveolar ridge (the fleshy ridge behind the upper teeth), and the target is somewhat behind (farther to the top of the mouth) where that of a hard /d/ would be. That's what I meant when I said it's de-emphasized and reduced. It's very quick as well. I suggest you listen to recordings of native speakers making that sound and try to emulate what you hear.

Comment: Give **[this link](http://www.englishlanguageclub.co.uk/t-sound/)** a try.

Comment: @P.E.Dant That is exactly _not_ the sound the OP is trying to make. The OP wants to do the 't' sound in the middle of a word like Americans do it. That video is for British English where the 't' is almost always aspirated. Americans __do not__ have a puff of air after the 'tt' in 'better' or 'twitter'.

Comment: @Mitch Well, this American does, but I admit to being something of a cultural mongrel. The OP doesn't specify NAmE or BrE. I chose that link because, from Dannie's comment, it is the aspiration that she (a wild guess at gender) is having trouble producing. You raise a useful point, though: some additional information from the OP would help us.

Comment: @Dannie Can you tell us, please, whether you want to pronounce _better_ and _letter_ as they are pronounced in American English or in British English? There is a noticeable difference between the two!

Comment: It's obvious the OP wants the American English pronunciation. Standard  British English doesn't use a flap t (alveolar flap or tap).

Comment: Open your mouth slightly. Now lay your tongue under your top teeth so that with your tongue you can feel all your back top teeth and your tongue is under them and the tip of your tongue is just touching the back of your front teeth.  Now curl the tip of your tongue straight upwards so it is now touching the top of your mouth but the back of the tongue is still under the back top teeth. (If you put your finger in your mouth it should go from the tip of the finger to the first joint before it touches the curled up part of the tongue.)  Now make the "t" sound by rapidly blowing air.  Viola!

Comment: @Clare Right you are; I was inattentive. To atone, I asked my Yoruba friend Adedayo who can, when he wishes, perfectly imitate a flat Midwestern accent, how he learned such things. He responded immediately: "Oh, it was Rachel!" He directed me to her YouTube offerings, e.g. **[this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7FUneS1mBs)** I watched a bit and didn't find her irritating.

Comment: but I know how to pronounce the T and the D what i don't know how to pronounce is the flap/tap t or the soft d which is in american english and aussie english

Comment: @Dannie Have you looked at the video at Rachel's English: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7FUneS1mBs

Comment: i have and it didn't help! ;[ i still pronounce it like a strong D not a soft D

Answer (score 1):

Being neither a speech therapist nor a physician, allow me to make a simple suggestion without the use of jargon (technical terms) for speaking American English:

1. Start to pronounce each of your sample words as if you intended to make the hard D or T sound
2. When your tongue is on the roof of your mouth, rather than forcing the tongue down (with your breath), relax the tongue so that a gap is formed
3. Continue with the next syllable (-er, -o)

Please let me know how this works for you!
Although using the softer D/T will sound more native, you will likely find it beneficial to be able to replace the soft D/T with the harder D/T for better clarity when singing or speaking to a large group.